# Is it right to say "Your leg touched mine"?

Tags: word-usage

On a bus, if the leg of someone near you comes into contact with yours, can you say “Your leg touched mine”? Or is “touch” only used when hands are involved? Thank you.

Comment: You can have "The tyre touched the kerb".

Comment: So “Your leg touched mine” is right?

Comment: Consult a dictionary for uses of “touch”.

Comment: It's helpful to say "I've looked it up in the dictionary but I still don't understand [this part]".

Comment: Talk to someone on the bus!!!

Comment: It's not a part in the dictionary that I don't understand. What I asked is outside what the dictionary covers. It’s helpful to read what I wrote.

Comment: How do you know I didn’t talk to someone on the bus? Talking to someone on the bus and asking a question here are not mutually exclusive. You’re stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The word "touched" only means contact was made. It does not refer to whether it is voluntary, accidental or involuntary, nor to whether the things touching are animate or inanimate. The short answer is yes you can say it.